# Is there any reason not to simply use a hashed session ID as the CSRF token?

Tags: security, session, csrf

I’ve been binging articles about how to correctly protect against CSRF attacks, wanting to fully understand what it is that I’m doing, and most of the articles I’ve read mention very little about how to actually generate a secure CSRF token.

I’ll use https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-custom-request-headers as an example, since it’s the article I see most referenced.

It doesn’t give any specific recommendations for generating a secure token, but does say this about per-session tokens:

> CSRF tokens should be:
>
> - Unique per user session.
> - Secret
> - Unpredictable (large random value generated by a secure method).

> the value is stored in the session and is used for each subsequent request until the session expires.

Which is generally what I see recommended for per-session token generation. That the token should be persisted in the cache/database along with the other session data.

Even the "Double Submit Cookie" technique in the above article specifies allocating a new cookie for transmitting the token, along with encrypting and decrypting the token using server secrets, etc.

However, is there really any reason to be generating and storing a new piece of data?

Would it not suffice to simply hash the session cookie and use that as the CSRF token? Then, when a request is received, check if the result of hashing the received session cookie matches the received CSRF token?

A CSRF attacker would be unable to provide a valid token without knowing the session cookie, which we can assume that they don’t know, because the whole reason they’re attempting a CSRF attack in the first place is to take advantage of the fact that the logged in user has the session cookie which is unknown to them.

Moreover, if the attacker somehow obtains the CSRF token, the only access they then receive is the ability to perform CSRF attacks, since they can’t "unhash" the token in order to receive the session ID.

It’s stateless and most importantly it’s damn easy. The fact that I’m not seeing it recommended makes me think I might be missing something. Hoping to get some confirmation from people more familiar with the subject.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing myself. And I don't think you're missing anything.